# Progress Bar percentage with one value

Tags: c#, events, progress-bar

I need my progress bar to increase every time I raise an event. Therefore, every time a certain something happens, I increment an int value and I raise my event.

However, I don't know how many times my int value will be incremented, meaning I do not know how to convert my int value into percentage. Usually, I would do something like

```
(value/totalValue) *100
```

Since I do not know what my total value will be (this is actually what the progress bar is demonstrating), then I do not know how to progress the progress bar.

Any ideas?

Comment: Usually you can use the [marquee](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbarstyle.aspx) [style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.style.aspx) when you don't have a total, would that work?

Comment: I feel like if you don't know the extent of the processing you'll be doing, then a progress bar isn't the best way to display the progress.

Comment: If you have no way of knowing when the activity will end, you should set the bar into Marquee mode.

Comment: @MikeC That's what [Marquee mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.progressbarstyle.aspx) is for. So you can see that "something" is happening. Like the documentation says: `You can use the marquee style when you need to indicate progress is being made, but you cannot indicate the quantity of progress. `

Comment: You could also just add a temporary label that is incremented by your event handlers. This allows you to see numerically how many times it has been raised in real time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the marquee style progress bar. Thank you to everyone who suggested it.

Answer (score 0):

You could always assume there will be `n` more events. For example, if you always assume one more event. After the first, the bar will show 50%, the next event will show 66%, then 75%. If you used 10, the first would show 9%, then 17%, 23%. You could adjust 'n' to find something that works with the approximate number you are expecting.

Comment: I don't believe this is an appropriate solution in any case. If it's unknown when the operation will end or how long it will take, don't lie to the user that you're 50% done after the first operation, when you don't know how many there will be. See: http://i.stack.imgur.com/CFuan.png

Comment: This assumes the approximate number of operations is known. I wouldn't use this method if there could be anywhere from 1 to 1000. But if it could be 1-5ish, I think it would be ok to use this method. Or if there was 100-120, just adjust 'n' accordingly. But you are correct, if it nothing is known about the final number, this would be misleading. I do know I don't like the Marquee style progress bars, but that’s a personal preference.